# cfwheels and object helpers

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I've got a set of processes I frequently do to a model that I keep redoing in the controller, and I'm wondering if there is a way to implement it through a function in the model, so that I can just call the model function pass some parameters and get the right query.

I've got a linked list, and there's a bit of repetition that I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out...

in model:

```
<cffunction name="getCustomResults" returntype="query">
    <cfset all = findAll()>
    <!--- do stuff --->
    <cfreturn myQuery>
</cffunction>
```

getting the custom results

```
<cfset mySelection = model('myModel').getCustomResults()>
```

Comment: You may have been just rushing to get that code down as an example, but don't forget to `var` or `local` scope your `all` variable.

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a way to do implement it through a function in the model

Can you please tell what stops you from doing exactly this? Simply create CFC like `/models/Foo.cfc` where `foo` is name of your model and extend it with methods. Just don't forget to extend the `Model.cfc`. See [this docs section](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/chapter/object-relational-mapping). Inside the model you have `this` scope which holds all properties.

Comment: Also, if this is functionality needed in every model, just define the function directly within models/Model.cfc